# How do we know in apex whether the context is executed from Flow asynchronous

Tags: invocable-method, salesforce-flow

I have a scenario where I'm inserting a record in future, and there is a flow automation on that object.

- The flow has an async path which is invoking an apex action.
- **How do I know within that that the context is flow async**?

  - As of now the quiddity is returning as Invocable action.

Also in the future method where I'm inserting the record, I am enqueuing a queueable job,

- later here in the invocable apex action I'm able to enqueue one more queuable job.
- Usually in future context, we cannot enqueue more than 1 queueable job.
- **How exactly does the flow async work**?,

Interestingly, the flow is triggered from future context, and the flow has an async path, I was expecting future from future error. I didn't get even that. I am wondering how the async flow path is handled in a transaction @sfdcfox

Comment: System.isFuture or System.isQueueable or System.isBatchable doesn't work, even though the flow is invoked from a future context.

Comment: can you use the Limits class to see if operating in an async context?

Comment: @cropredy it is operating in an async context. I'm wondering what are the limitations of using async execution in a flow. As in how many flow async can be invoked in a transaction? If we know limitations/consideration, we can use it better.

Answer (score -1):

You can use System.Quiddity,
Request reqInfo = Request.getCurrent();
System.debug(reqInfo.getQuiddity());
When its async it will b INVOCABLE_ACTION

Comment: The question says: "... quiddity is returning as Invocable action..." So you're just repeating one thing from the question, or not?